# How can I add metadata to a PDF with Delphi - im my case the DOI?

Tags: delphi, doi

How can I add the document object identifier (DOI) to a PDF File with Delphi XE6? Is there a tool (also commercial one) available?
Thanks
Walter

Comment: You could also get familiar with the PDF binary format and then add/modify/delete the PDF document using `TBinaryWriter` and `TBinaryReader` classes.

Comment: I do not think That The doi (which is usually in the subject line, as far as I have discovered) is in the binary ! I think that is in the metadata!

Comment: File is an array of bytes. A digital object identifier (DOI) is a character string. Strings are bytes.

Comment: Ok, do you know how I can write a example which writes to a PDF a new and longer DOI?

Comment: @RawN you are right. In the PDF there is an ASCII LINE like this `8 0 obj<</Producer(iText 1.4 \(by lowagie.com\))/ModDate(D:20150502092708Z)/CreationDate(D:20150502092708Z) /Subject (hier is the doi inside) >> `

Comment: After inserting that string I suspect you would need to adjust the numbers in the last PDF section.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: [3rd party tool](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp)
this tool can write/read metadata from a pdf.
the doi stands in the Subject field.
Works great with Delphi XE6!